# Push additional custom variable in transactional event at Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have set up a transaction custom event in google tag manager with the name 'purchase' (as in documentation) and we are pushing with the following code correctly:

```
(<any>window).dataLayer.push({
            event: 'purchase',
            transactionId: id,
            transactionTotal: totalPrice,
            transactionTax: 0.0,
            transactionShipping: 0.0,
            transactionProducts: products,
        });
```

where products is another array-object.

This works fine but we wanted to add another one variable(transactionCustomVariable) in the above json like the following:

```
(<any>window).dataLayer.push({
            event: 'purchase',
            transactionCustomVariable: 0,
            transactionId: id,
            transactionTotal: totalPrice,
            transactionTax: 0.0,
            transactionShipping: 0.0,
            transactionProducts: products,
        });
```

and it seems we cannot pass this value to google tag manager.

Is there a specific naming convention on new fields for a Transactional Event.
We have created the variable name. Is there anything we are missing there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you see that the variable isn't passing through ?
You should see it in the GTM debug mode, as an update to dataLayer, on 'purchase' GTM event. Do you mean passing a Custom Dimension value to Google Analytics ? or to GTM ?

Comment: yes @OpenSEO this is what i meant. i am relatively a beginner in this part so i thought that the dimensions would be auto-created in a transactional event by following the same naming convention. but i believe you have to create the dimension manually. is this also the case for this transaction event?

Comment: better you express / formulate what you provide and where, and what you expect to see, even without knowing the tools, and better you understand what is the missing part

Comment: does the answer fits your question ?

Comment: yes @OpenSEO i figured it out thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA native tags in GTM can handle "transparently" values from the dataLayer when it follows a given naming convention designed to collect Enhanced eCommerce tracking details

See 
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#data-layer

When you want to push additional values to GA, you can decide to reserve slots for data storage in GA, called Custom Dimension or Custom Metric.
These slots can have different scope: User, Session, Hit, Product and are defined by an Index (in the admin interface)

When you need to populate Product scope values, you have a naming convention to follow for automatic handling from the eCommerce dataLayer to the GA hit, since it is specific to Enhanced eCommerce
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#custom-dimensions

For every other scope of Custom Dimension / Metric, in GTM you need to explicit the mapping between the dataLayer Attribute => a GTM Variable (possibly with a different name) => the Custom Dimension / Metric Index defined in the GA admin interface.

I recommend you use a [GA Settings Variable](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#14-google-analytics-settings) to define that mapping only once and use it for every hit.

You may also use a dataLayer attribute in other tags than GA, you'll be able to use the same GTM Variable to access its value and map to parameters of those tags.

I recommend that you first audit how the dataLayer gets updated when you push data, with the help of the GTM debug mode.
Next, you verify that the tag using that value is consuming it properly and pushing it forward, if applicable.

I suggest that you use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom that allows auditing of both dataLayer and GA hits

Comment: thanks for your detailed feedback and sorry for the late response!